# Javascript load directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few radiobuttons and a few drop down menus that show/hide depending on which radiobutton is selected, however my first three (of six) radiobuttons doesnt activate the JS code directly!

https://jsfiddle.net/spfrh9h8/

Check this fiddle out to get a visual of what Im trying to say.
While the 'Primary' radio is selected, no dropdown should be visible, as it wont be if you press it, however, when it is selected and page is reloaded, (still selected) the dropdown will be there visible again when it shouldn't. I'm pretty sure this is an easy fix but I couldn't figure it out.

```
$(function() {
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 1  && this.checked) {
                $("#exerVariNameS").show();
                $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == 2  && this.checked){
                $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameB").show();
                $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == 3  && this.checked) {
                $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                $("#exerVariNameD").show();
                $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
            }
        });

        $("input[name='Type']").click(function(){
                var value=$(this).val();
            switch(value){
                case '4':
                $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                    $(this).closest('div').show();
                });
                $('#dropdown').hide();
                $('#exerVariNameA').hide();
                break;
              case '5':
                $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                  $(this).closest('div').show();
                });
                $('#dropdown').show();
                $('#exerVariNameA').hide();
                break;
              case '6':
                $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                  $(this).closest('div').hide();
                });
                $('#dropdown').hide();
                $('#exerVariNameA').show();
                break;
            }
        });
        //Remember which radiobutton was last clicked and keeps it that way
        //after a page refresh or form post.
        $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
            var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );
            if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
            $(this).trigger('change');
        });
        $("input[name='Type']").each(function(){
            var state=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('radio_val'+this.value));
          if(state) this.checked=state.checked;
          $(this).trigger('change');
        });
        $(window).bind('unload', function() {
            $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                localStorage.setItem('radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked}));
            });
            $("input[name='Type']").each(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('radio_val'+this.value,JSON.stringify({checked:this.checked}));
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you can trigger the click on the first radio when the page loads `$(document).ready(function() {$('input[type=radio]:first-child').trigger('click');});`.

Comment: Well, it did work, but came with some complications, that dropdown that disappears when 'Primary' is clicked should not disappear when 'Secondary' is clicked, and since it remember which was clicked via localstorage, if 'Secondary' is selected before reload, the box is visible, but then after reload it becomes hidden since primary is triggered. However, I dont need the first three radios to remember last one selected on reload but since I didnt write this javascript myself and dont understand very much of it, I dont know how to do that while still making the last three radios ..to be continued

Comment: ...while still making the last three radios remember last selected value! I'd be fine with Primary being selected each time the page reloads as well, as long as the correct stuff are shown/hidden haha. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could check the localStorage and trigger the according radio instead of triggering always the first one.

Comment: I see, how would one achieve such a thing if I may ask?

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function that gets triggered on document load. Inside this function you can trigger the radio button you want.

Ex: Trigger always the first radio on document load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

Ex: Trigger last radio selected by user (according to localStorage).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    radio_val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('radio_'+this.id));
    if (radio_val.checked) {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

For this last block to work there are missing `IDs` on your markup.

Here:

```
<input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ4" value="4" />
```

Here:

```
<input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ5" value="5" />
```

And here:

```
<input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ6" value="6" />
```

See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spfrh9h8/6/).

Comment: That my friend, is absolutely fantastic! Hugely appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

just add two hides on starting of the function

```js
$(function() {
$('#dropdown').hide();
                    $('#exerVariNameA').hide();
            $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == 1  && this.checked) {
                    $("#exerVariNameS").show();
                    $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
                } else if ($(this).val() == 2  && this.checked){
                    $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameB").show();
                    $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
                } else if ($(this).val() == 3  && this.checked) {
                    $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
                    $("#exerVariNameD").show();
                    $("#exerVariNameA").hide();
                }
            });

            $("input[name='Type']").click(function(){
              var value=$(this).val();
                switch(value){
                 case '4':
                   $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                     $(this).closest('div').show();
                    });
                    $('#dropdown').hide();
                    $('#exerVariNameA').hide();
                    break;
                  case '5':
                    $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                      $(this).closest('div').show();
                    });
                    $('#dropdown').show();
                    $('#exerVariNameA').hide();
                    break;
                  case '6':
                    $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                      $(this).closest('div').hide();
                    });
                    $('#dropdown').hide();
                    $('#exerVariNameA').show();
                    break;
                }
            });
            //Remember which radiobutton was last clicked and keeps it that way
            //after a page refresh or form post.
            $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );
                if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
                $(this).trigger('change');
            });
            $("input[name='Type']").each(function(){
             var state=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('radio_val'+this.value));
              if(state) this.checked=state.checked;
              $(this).trigger('change');
            });
            $(window).bind('unload', function() {
                $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked}));
                });
                $("input[name='Type']").each(function(){
                 localStorage.setItem('radio_val'+this.value,JSON.stringify({checked:this.checked}));
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Well, that kind of solved half of it! If 'Secondary' radio was selected from the start it should be visible, as well as when 'Assistance' is selected (but in case of 'Assistance' the second group of radios will dissapear, as they do on click but not on page reload if selected fromthe start). Because it remembers which radio was last selected so it doesnt select the first radio by default on page reload.

Comment: The second group of radios ('Squat', 'Benchpress' and 'Deadlift') shows and hides different dropdowns, and those are correctly loaded/hidden/shown on page reload so I would just like for the first group of radios to do the same (load correctly from start will say) :/